# Twilio C# SendMessage suddenly returning null

Tags: c#, twilio, sendmessage

We've been using the twilio C# client for asp.net MVC for a long time without trouble.  It recently stopped working, with SendMessage returning null.  Investigation suggests some kind of SSL issue.  https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/issues/126

I suspect this has something to do with dropping support for SSLv3.  https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/10/security-notification-for-sslv3-poodle-vulnerability.html

Unfortunately we ring-fenced our Microsoft development years ago (all new development is linux/rails) so we're stuck using a bunch of old windows crap.  I'm stuck on VS2005 and had to build the twilio c# client myself.   Rebuilding the DLLs from the latest github source hasn't helped.

I can send SMS my old windows xp development machine with .net 3.5, but not in production on windows 2003R2.

This didn't help

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

and don't have TLS 1.2 in .net 3.5 so can't do this

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

What can we do?

Comment: I maybe barking up the wrong tree.  The SSLv3 deprecation happened over a year ago!

Comment: Are you able to run fiddler and see what communication is going on? Also; `TLS1.0` is typically regarded as unsafe, and is being phased out much the same as `SSL3` has been. I'd highly recommend finding a solution which allows you to use `Tls12` (I'm not familiar with `.NET 3.5`, but I would imagine there is a library; if not, you may have to upgrade). If indeed it is an issue with your security protocols, it's going to happen again in the (maybe?) nearish future with `TLS1.0`

Comment: Thanks for the fiddler suggestion - Session #2: The remote server (api.twilio.com) presented a certificate that did not validate, due to RemoteCertificateChainErrors.

0 - Unknown error.

SUBJECT: CN=*.twilio.com, OU=api, O="Twilio, Inc.", L=San Francisco, S=California, C=US
ISSUER: CN=thawte SSL CA - G2, O="thawte, Inc.", C=US
EXPIRES: 17/09/2016 9:59:59 AM

Comment: You will have to install the certificate(s) on your remote server. Go to `https://api.twilio.com`, Click on the lock icon, open certificates (depends on which browser you have, the steps may be different). Go to certification path. Click the top cert. Click view certificate. Then details -> Copy to file and select BASE64 encoded. Copy that file up to your server, and double click it. Install it under the computer's `Root certificates` store.

Comment: ***Make sure you trust this certificate provider!***. Thawte is generally reliable but you should be certain it's the correct certificate (in case you are currently experiencing a MITM attack) which is what caused this error in the first place. You can double check this by checking existing certificates in your store. If you find *any* which are in the chain - and have not expired - you should be highly suspicious before proceeding.

Comment: I did this as well as attempting to install the entire thawte certificate bundle.  I copied the certs into the local machine's certificates but have received no joy.  I can browse using firefox now, but neither fiddler or the application can  connect.  I'll try the port 8443 stop gap, and begin the migration to server 2012. Thanks again.

Comment: What I am about to suggest is NOT a long term solution, but just to test if a certificate error is your issue you can effectively turn off certificate validation in .Net by putting this code early in the execution of your app: `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (mender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is an SSL/TLS issue in that we recently upgraded the SSL certificate for api.twilio.com to a SHA2-signed certificate.

To mitigate this change right now, you can update your application to use api.twilio.com:8443 which is maintaining the old certificate. However that will only be available until the end of this year (31 December 2015).

To fix it overall, you will likely need to update your SSL libraries. I'm afraid I do not know how to do that on the Windows servers you mention.

Please see [this post for more details and ways to test](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/december-ssl-certificate-update-prevents-twilio-api-access).

Comment: Praise the lord.  Thank you.  That worked and gives us some breathing space.

Comment: Installing the following hotfix on our 2003R2 server fixed it.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/968730